# How do you solve a triangle given one angle and only a part of one side?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

[image]

I'm not asking for the answer, I just can't figure out what steps to take to solve for the radius.

I get something like $\sin(76.6) = r/(r + 112)$, but I don't know where to go from there. Or if that's even the right direction to go in.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have the equation $\sin(76.6^\circ) = r/(r+112)$. Now all you need to do is solve for $r$. A good first step would be to multiply both sides by $r+112$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(76.6^\circ)=\frac r{r+112}$ is a great place to start.  All you have to do is substitute in $\sin(76.6^\circ)\approx0.973$ and multiply both sides by $r+112$ and you have a three-step equation in one unknown.

Comment: I tried that the first time and got stuck. I had r - r (sin (76.6)) and just blanked. Factoring for r (1 - sin76.6) didn't occur to me until I revisited it. Knowing I was on the right track made a difference. Thanks